# Calculate distance from selected index in a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm rather a programmer than a mathematician, and recently I had a problem that I can't solve.
Suppose I have a ring sequence of numbers, for example

```
0 1 2 3
9     4
8 7 6 5
```

also I have some index in the sequence in relation to which I want to calculate the distance from the index for each number in the sequence.

For example, for index=2 and sequence [0,1,2,3,4] :

```
Sequence: 0 1 2 3 4
Distance: 2 1 0 1 2
```

or

```
Sequence: 3 4 0 1 2
Distance: 2 1 0 1 2
```

For the first case I can calculate the distance using this formula:

```
d = mod(s - i), where
d - distance,
s - selected index,
i - index in the sequnce
```

But unfortunately that doesn't work for the second case.
Is there some way to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The distance between $s$ and $i$ is 
$$ \min\{|s-i|, m-|s-i|\}.$$

Note that $|s-i|$ is the distance when crossing from $m-1$ to $0$ is not allowed, and $m-$ the former is the distance the other way round.

Comment: Yes, it occurred to me, but I would like to calculate the value without conditional operators, if that's possible.